# Deploy Azure function using FTP

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-functions

I am adding new function in a existing azure function app using FTP. This function should trigger automatically when specified subscription to service bus topic receives message. I can see function appearing in portal but it is not triggering automatically. But I can soon as I save function.json from kudu. It triggers automatically after that. [Image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygECj.jpg).
Is it because trigger is not getting getting registered when I add function function via ftp?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, triggers don't get synced properly when using FTP (known issue). After uploading your files, you can go to the Portal and click the refresh icon next to the Function App name to cause a sync. It's also possible via PowerShell (see [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/7695096e923a2e6e1f697f1645685917f966cde9/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L362-L367)).